# Removing Duplicates From a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

My situation is that I am trying to clean up a data set of student results for processing and I'm having some issues with completely removing duplicates as only wanting to look at "first attempts" but some students have taken the course multiple times. An example of the data using one of the duplicates is:

```
        id     period                                           desc
632   1507       1101 90714 Research a contemporary biological issue
633   1507       1101         6317 Explain the process of speciation
634   1507       1101                  8931 Describe gene expression
14448 1507       1201                  8931 Describe gene expression
14449 1507       1201         6317 Explain the process of speciation
14450 1507       1201 90714 Research a contemporary biological issue
25884 1507       1301         6317 Explain the process of speciation
25885 1507       1301                  8931 Describe gene expression
25886 1507       1301 90714 Research a contemporary biological issue
```

The first 2 digits of `reg_period` are the year they sat the paper. As can be seen, I would want to be keeping where `id` is 1507 and `reg_period` is 1101. So far, an example of my code to get the values I want to be trimming is:

```
unique.rows <- unique(df[c("id", "period")])
dups <- (unique.rows[duplicated(unique.rows$id),])
```

However, there are a couple of problems I am then running in to. This only works because the data is ordered by `id` and `reg_period` and this isn't guaranteed in future. Plus I don't know how to then take this list of duplicate entries and then select the rows that are not in it because `%in%` doesn't seem to work with it and a loop with `rbind` runs out of memory.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Regarding this relying on the order of the data - this is fine, you just need to sort first so you can guarantee the order. `df = df[order(df$id, df$period), ]`.

Comment: As for the other part, `%in%` doesn't change its behavior in a `for` loop, it should work just fine. Though there's  certainly a better way.

Comment: As to the better way, I want to make sure I understand your goal. Is it just for every unique `id`, you want to keep all rows with the smallest `period` value? The `desc` doesn't matter at all? Or is it for every `id`, for every `desc` you want to keep the row with the smallest `period`?

Comment: For every `id`, I want to keep the smallest `period` value only. There will be a later issue with the marks for each `desc` (as over time there have been overlaps with changing descriptions) but I hope understanding how to do this with `id` and `period` will teach me how to do it for that situation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use `dplyr`. Calling your data `df`:

```
result = df %>% group_by(id) %>%
    filter(period == min(period))
```

If you prefer `base`, I would pull the `id`/`period` combinations to keep into a separate data frame and then do an inner join with the original data:

```
id_pd = df[order(df$id, df$pd), c("id", "period")]
id_pd = id_pd[!duplicated(df$id), ]
result = merge(df, id_pd)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a feeling it was possible with `dplyr` but I'm still too inexperienced with it. That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me with your data:

```
dd <- read.csv("a.csv", colClasses=c("numeric","numeric","character"), header=TRUE)
print (dd)
dd <- dd[order(dd$id, dd$period), ]
dd <- dd[!duplicated(dd[, c("id","period")]), ]
print (dd)
```

Output:

```
    id period                                           desc
1 1507   1101 90714 Research a contemporary biological issue
4 1507   1201                  8931 Describe gene expression
7 1507   1301         6317 Explain the process of speciation
```

Comment: The problem with this output is that you have one `id` from each `period`, not all rows are from the `period` 1101

Comment: Then I don't understand something. All values for id are 1507. Can you show what you want for the sample data you have here?

Comment: For each id, OP wants to keep only the rows with the first/smallest period - but keep all rows with that period.